# WaitExten during the call

Tags: asterisk

Scenario:

1. Asterisk receives incoming call to a DID number
2. Asterisk forwards incoming call to a mobile number using PSTN termination.
3. Call is answered on a mobile

Question:

Is there a possibility to transfer call to a different extension during the call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,but require guru level.

it can be done by writing special application or using conference or using AMI.

probably easy way is conference

Comment: Thank you! I've found conference is suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This is very straight forward.

Presuming your DID is 1-234-567-8900 and your moble is 1-987-654-3210:

```
exten => _12345678900,1,NoOp(Call for DID to Mobile)
 same => n, Dial(DAHDI/g1/19876543210,30,t)
 same => n, HangUp()
```

The dial option "t" allows "*...the called user to transfer the call by hitting the blind xfer keys (features.conf)*"

Further reading: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial